# Can't access the admin panel "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1

newbie here with not much knowledge in coding.
Through Magentoconnect downloader, I tried to update the modules with new stable versions.
something happened and the thing crashed and i had to dig here to find out and delete the maintinanceFlag file.
now the site and the downloader are back online as before. Except for the Amin panel. it shows "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/ABCDE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 400.
i got to the file and the code reads:

```
<?php
/**
* Magento
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
* needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
*
* @category    Mage
* @package     Mage_Adminhtml
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
* @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*/

 /**
   * Base adminhtml controller
   *
   * @category    Mage
   * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
   * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
   */
   class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
{
/**
 * Name of "is URLs checked" flag
 */
const FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED = 'check_url_settings';

/**
 * Session namespace to refer in other places
 */
const SESSION_NAMESPACE = 'adminhtml';

/**
 * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_publicActions = array();

/**
 * Used module name in current adminhtml controller
 */
protected $_usedModuleName = 'adminhtml';

/**
 * Currently used area
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_currentArea = 'adminhtml';

/**
 * Namespace for session.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_sessionNamespace = self::SESSION_NAMESPACE;

protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin');
}

/**
 * Retrieve adminhtml session model object
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session
 */
protected function _getSession()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
}

/**
 * Retrieve base admihtml helper
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data
 */
protected function _getHelper()
{
    return Mage::helper('adminhtml');
}

/**
 * Define active menu item in menu block
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
protected function _setActiveMenu($menuPath)
{
"    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
protected function _addBreadcrumb($label, $title, $link=null)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->addLink($label, $title, $link);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
protected function _addContent(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    return $this;
}

protected function _addLeft(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($block);
    return $this;
}

protected function _addJs(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('js')->append($block);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Controller predispatch method
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
public function preDispatch()
{
    // override admin store design settings via stores section
    Mage::getDesign()
        ->setArea($this->_currentArea)
        ->setPackageName((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/package/name'))
        ->setTheme((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/theme/default'))
    ;
    foreach (array('layout', 'template', 'skin', 'locale') as $type) {
        if ($value = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin
/design/theme/{$type}')) {
            Mage::getDesign()->setTheme($type, $value);
        }
    }

    $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);

    Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start', array());
    parent::preDispatch();
    $_isValidFormKey = true;
    $_isValidSecretKey = true;
    $_keyErrorMsg = '';
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $_isValidFormKey = $this->_validateFormKey();
            $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.');
        } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
            $_isValidSecretKey = $this->_validateSecretKey();
            $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.');
        }
    }
    if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax', false) || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax', false)) {
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $_keyErrorMsg
            )));
        } else {
            $this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
        }
        return $this;
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isDispatched()
        && $this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'denied'
        && !$this->_isAllowed()) {
        $this->_forward('denied');
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        return $this;
    }

    if (!$this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED)
        && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('forwarded')
        && !$this->_getSession()->getIsUrlNotice(true)
        && !Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/can_use_base_url')) {
        //$this->_checkUrlSettings();
        $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED, true);
    }
    if (is_null(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getLocale())) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setLocale(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode());
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @deprecated after 1.4.0.0 alpha, logic moved to Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Baseurl
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
protected function _checkUrlSettings()
{
    /**
     * Don't check for data saving actions
     */
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost() || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax')) {
        return $this;
    }

    $configData = Mage::getModel('core/config_data');

    $defaultUnsecure = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
        'default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL
    );
    $defaultSecure = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
        'default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL
    );

    if ($defaultSecure == '{{base_url}}' || $defaultUnsecure == '{{base_url}}') {
        $this->_getSession()->addNotice(
            $this->__('{{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento <a href='%s'>configuration</a>.', $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section'=>'web')))
        );
        return $this;
    }

    $dataCollection = $configData->getCollection()
        ->addValueFilter('{{base_url}}');

    $url = false;
    foreach ($dataCollection as $data) {
        if ($data->getScope() == 'stores') {
            $code = Mage::app()->getStore($data->getScopeId())->getCode();
            $url = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section'=>'web', 'store'=>$code));
        }
        if ($data->getScope() == 'websites') {
            $code = Mage::app()->getWebsite($data->getScopeId())->getCode();
            $url = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section'=>'web', 'website'=>$code));
        }

        if ($url) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(
                $this->__('{{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento <a href='%s'>configuration</a>.', $url)
            );
            return $this;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function deniedAction()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','403 Forbidden');
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/index/login');
        return;
    }
    $this->loadLayout(array('default', 'adminhtml_denied'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function loadLayout($ids=null, $generateBlocks=true, $generateXml=true)
{
    parent::loadLayout($ids, $generateBlocks, $generateXml);
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session');
    return $this;
}

public function norouteAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
    $this->loadLayout(array('default', 'adminhtml_noroute'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}


/**
 * Retrieve currently used module name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsedModuleName()
{
    return $this->_usedModuleName;
}

/**
 * Set currently used module name
 *
 * @param string $moduleName
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
public function setUsedModuleName($moduleName)
{
    $this->_usedModuleName = $moduleName;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Translate a phrase
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $expr = new Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr(array_shift($args), $this->getUsedModuleName());
    array_unshift($args, $expr);
    return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args);
}

/**
 * Set referer url for redirect in responce
 *
 * Is overriden here to set defaultUrl to admin url
 *
 * @param   string $defaultUrl
 * @return  Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 */
protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
{
    $defaultUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? $this->getUrl('*') : $defaultUrl;
    parent::_redirectReferer($defaultUrl);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set redirect into responce
 *
 * @param   string $path
 * @param   array $arguments
 */
protected function _redirect($path, $arguments=array())
{
    $this->_getSession()->setIsUrlNotice($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED));
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl($path, $arguments));
    return $this;
}

protected function _forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)
{
    $this->_getSession()->setIsUrlNotice($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED));
    return parent::_forward($action, $controller, $module, $params);
}

/**
 * Generate url by route and parameters
 *
 * @param   string $route
 * @param   array $params
 * @return  string
 */
public function getUrl($route='', $params=array())
{
    return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl($route, $params);
}

/**
 * Validate Secret Key
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _validateSecretKey()
{
    if (is_array($this->_publicActions) && in_array($this->getRequest()->getActionName(), $this->_publicActions)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!($secretKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME, null))
        || $secretKey != Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey())         {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
/**
 * Validate password for current admin user
 *
 * @param string $password - current password
 *
 * @return mixed - returns true or array of errors
 */
 /**   protected function _validateCurrentPassword($password)
{
 $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
 return $user->validateCurrentPassword($password);
}
}
```

I apologies its too long and the error is in line 400 (last) but i have no clue what to do and need to get it back online asap.

Comment: Roll back your update to the last stable backup/commit you have (you have one right!?)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the double-quote, line 104.

Answer (score 1):

Boy you have an unclosed double quote under the `_setActiveMenu` declaration ( under the { )

That should be the problem

BTW try to use an IDE or at least a code editor app.

Answer (score 1):

Replace you file content with below:

```
<?php

/**
 * Base adminhtml controller
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
{
    /**
     * Name of "is URLs checked" flag
     */
    const FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED = 'check_url_settings';

    /**
     * Session namespace to refer in other places
     */
    const SESSION_NAMESPACE = 'adminhtml';

    /**
     * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_publicActions = array();

    /**
     * Used module name in current adminhtml controller
     */
    protected $_usedModuleName = 'adminhtml';

    /**
     * Currently used area
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_currentArea = 'adminhtml';

    /**
     * Namespace for session.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_sessionNamespace = self::SESSION_NAMESPACE;

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve adminhtml session model object
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session
     */
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base admihtml helper
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data
     */
    protected function _getHelper()
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml');
    }

    /**
     * Define active menu item in menu block
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _setActiveMenu($menuPath)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _addBreadcrumb($label, $title, $link = null)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->addLink($label, $title, $link);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _addContent(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addLeft(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($block);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addJs(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('js')->append($block);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Controller predispatch method
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
// override admin store design settings via stores section
        Mage::getDesign()
            ->setArea($this->_currentArea)
            ->setPackageName((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/package/name'))
            ->setTheme((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/theme/default'));
        foreach (array('layout', 'template', 'skin', 'locale') as $type) {
            if ($value = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin
/design/theme/{$type}')
            ) {
                Mage::getDesign()->setTheme($type, $value);
            }
        }

        $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start', array());
        parent::preDispatch();
        $_isValidFormKey = true;
        $_isValidSecretKey = true;
        $_keyErrorMsg = '';
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $_isValidFormKey = $this->_validateFormKey();
                $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.');
            } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
                $_isValidSecretKey = $this->_validateSecretKey();
                $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.');
            }
        }
        if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax', false) || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax', false)) {
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => $_keyErrorMsg
                )));
            } else {
                $this->_redirect(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl());
            }
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isDispatched()
            && $this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'denied'
            && !$this->_isAllowed()
        ) {
            $this->_forward('denied');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED)
            && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('forwarded')
            && !$this->_getSession()->getIsUrlNotice(true)
            && !Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/can_use_base_url')
        ) {
//$this->_checkUrlSettings();
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED, true);
        }
        if (is_null(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getLocale())) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setLocale(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated after 1.4.0.0 alpha, logic moved to Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Baseurl
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _checkUrlSettings()
    {
        /**
         * Don't check for data saving actions
         */
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost() || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax')) {
            return $this;
        }

        $configData = Mage::getModel('core/config_data');

        $defaultUnsecure = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
            'default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL
        );
        $defaultSecure = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
            'default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL
        );

        if ($defaultSecure == '{{base_url}}' || $defaultUnsecure == '{{base_url}}') {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(
                $this->__('{{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento <a href="%s">configuration</a>.', $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section' => 'web'))));
            return $this;
        }

        $dataCollection = $configData->getCollection()
            ->addValueFilter('{{base_url}}');

        $url = false;
        foreach ($dataCollection as $data) {
            if ($data->getScope() == 'stores') {
                $code = Mage::app()->getStore($data->getScopeId())->getCode();
                $url = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section' => 'web', 'store' => $code));
            }
            if ($data->getScope() == 'websites') {
                $code = Mage::app()->getWebsite($data->getScopeId())->getCode();
                $url = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section' => 'web', 'website' => $code));
            }

            if ($url) {
                $this->_getSession()->addNotice(
                    $this->__('{{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento <a href="%s">configuration</a>.', $url)
                );
                return $this;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function deniedAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '403 Forbidden');
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/index/login');
            return;
        }
        $this->loadLayout(array('default', 'adminhtml_denied'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function loadLayout($ids = null, $generateBlocks = true, $generateXml = true)
    {
        parent::loadLayout($ids, $generateBlocks, $generateXml);
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session');
        return $this;
    }

    public function norouteAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '404 Not Found');
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status', '404 File not found');
        $this->loadLayout(array('default', 'adminhtml_noroute'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve currently used module name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsedModuleName()
    {
        return $this->_usedModuleName;
    }

    /**
     * Set currently used module name
     *
     * @param string $moduleName
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    public function setUsedModuleName($moduleName)
    {
        $this->_usedModuleName = $moduleName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Translate a phrase
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $expr = new Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr(array_shift($args), $this->getUsedModuleName());
        array_unshift($args, $expr);
        return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args);
    }

    /**
     * Set referer url for redirect in responce
     *
     * Is overriden here to set defaultUrl to admin url
     *
     * @param   string $defaultUrl
     * @return  Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl = null)
    {
        $defaultUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? $this->getUrl('*') : $defaultUrl;
        parent::_redirectReferer($defaultUrl);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set redirect into responce
     *
     * @param   string $path
     * @param   array $arguments
     */
    protected function _redirect($path, $arguments = array())
    {
        $this->_getSession()->setIsUrlNotice($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED));
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl($path, $arguments));
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)
    {
        $this->_getSession()->setIsUrlNotice($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED));
        return parent::_forward($action, $controller, $module, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = array())
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl($route, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Validate Secret Key
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _validateSecretKey()
    {
        if (is_array($this->_publicActions) && in_array($this->getRequest()->getActionName(), $this->_publicActions)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!($secretKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME, null))
            || $secretKey != Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey()
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Validate password for current admin user
     *
     * @param string $password - current password
     *
     * @return mixed - returns true or array of errors
     */
    protected function _validateCurrentPassword($password)
    {
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        return $user->validateCurrentPassword($password);
    }
}
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh for the effort. now the message changed to: Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in /home/ABCDE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 80

Comment: Please check your Magento **exception.log** / **system.log** which might be logged any error related to this.